# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: for the matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I get the following error and unsure as to why? ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
The dataset I used is https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/demographic-statistics-by-zip-code-acfc9

I thought it was already converted to a matrix once it is in the dataframe. Especially because the plot data shows up correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#implmenting KNN in python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import operator
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import time
start_time = time.time()

#1) Ingest the data via one of the provided formats.

print("Getting csv")
###################################
#2.) Create a data structure to store the data.
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\trave.DESKTOP-KM5AM0U\Desktop\UNIT 5\Demographic_Statistics_By_Zip_Code.csv", usecols = ["COUNT PARTICIPANTS", "PERCENT RECEIVES PUBLIC ASSISTANCE"])
#msft.plot("JURISDICTION NAME", ["COUNT PUBLIC ASSISTANCE TOTAL", "COUNT PARTICIPANTS"], subplots=True)
# print("Entering data to datfram only 3 columns")
# print ("The number of rows is")
# print (len(data.index))
# print ("The number of columns is")
# print (len(data.columns))
print(data.head)

#################
print("running plots")
#scikit-learn
#####################################
#MATPLOT FOR REGRESSION LINE DATA
Par = data.iloc[:, 0]

Per = data.iloc[:, 1]

# Count_P = data[]
# Public_Aid = data[]



plt.title('Number of people to public aid percentage')
plt.xlabel('#Participant')
plt.ylabel('% Public aid')

plt.plot (Par, Per, 'k.')

plt.axis([.1,200,.1,1])
plt.grid(True)

print("plots complete")


###################################
print("sklearn running")

from  sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit (X=Par, y=Per)

print('SKLEARN MODULE COMPLETE')
#########################################
####making prediction
print("running prediction")

p = model.predict ([[78]]) [0][0]
print (round(p,2))





# STOP MY TIMER
print ("My program took", time.time() - start_time, "to run")
```

Comment: Because `Par` is 1D? You create it from a slice as `Par = data.iloc[:, 0]` which is a 1D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify `X` (`Par` in your case) -

From:

```
Par = data.iloc[:, 0]
```

To:

```
Par = data.iloc[:, [0]]
```

Comment: Thank you I had to do it for both Par and Per but runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `y` you used to fit the model is 1D, so will the result of the prediction from the model.

If you want to make a prediction from a unique value `x`, you can try:

```py
p = model.predict([[78]])[0]
```

p will be 1D, so you just need to get the index 0 once

Comment: Thank you I did upvote your answer. It was correct. I just had trouble figuring out how to convert the CVS to the 2 matrix. I even tried to transpose so it would be 1 row and lot of column. I appreciate all the help.